# force symbolic only links

Tags: bash

So, I had a brainfart and deleted some hardlinks (and the linked files as well).  I don't normally use hard links, so is there a better way to force symbolic links by default than

```
alias ln='ln -s'
```

in my `~/.bashrc`

?

Comment: I don't regard aliases like that as reliable.  And ones like `alias rm='rm -i'` are noxious as well as dangerous.  The best way is to make sure you create the right type of link because you know what you're doing.  Having been bitten, you're 'twice shy', which is fair enough.

Comment: Think twice, type once is obvious.  And I'm aware of the dangers of noxious aliases.  Nonetheless, I am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Deleting a hardlink doesn't delete the file unless the link count reaches 0. Unless, you mean you explicitly deleted the others also.

Comment: Well, I'm somewhat less ignorant now based on Leffler and FatalError's comments.  Renders the question pointless.  I've just voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest in this case, you create alias with another name, otherwise when you really want to create a hard-link, you have to type `\ln ...`  (or `link`)

if you have

```
alias lns='ln -s'
```

you could usually type `lns ...` for symbolic links, when you need to create hard link, you could type `ln...`. also you still have possibility to exercise typing `ln -s ...` manually....

hope it helps